# Oauth authentication in Apache SuperSet

Tags: python, docker, flask, flask-appbuilder, apache-superset

I'm trying to enable authentication in [Apache SuperSet](https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset) through Oauth2.

It shoud be straightforward due to the fact that it's built upon [Flask AppBuilder](https://github.com/dpgaspar/flask-appbuilder/) which supports OAuth and is extremely easy to setup and use.

I managed to make both the following examples work seamlessy with Twitter Oauth configuration:

1. [FAB OAuth example](https://github.com/dpgaspar/Flask-AppBuilder/tree/master/examples/oauth)
2. [flask-oauthlib examples](https://github.com/lepture/flask-oauthlib/tree/master/example)

Now I'm trying to apply the same configuration to SuperSet.

**Docker**

As I can't manually build the project for several mysterious python errors (tried on Windows 7/Ubuntu Linux and with Python versions 2.7 and 3.6), I decided to use [this Superset docker image](https://github.com/amancevice/superset) (that installs and works fine) and inject my configuration as suggested by [docs](https://github.com/amancevice/superset#configuration):

> Follow the instructions provided by Apache Superset for writing your own superset_config.py. Place this file in a local directory and mount this directory to /home/superset/.superset inside the container.

I added a `superset_config.py` (in a folder and alone) and mounted it by adding to the `Dockerfile` the following:

```
ADD config .superset/config
```

(`config` is the name of the folder) or (for the single file):

```
COPY superset_config.py .superset
```

In both cases the files end up in the right place in the container (I check with `docker exec /bin/bash`) but the web application shows no difference: no traces of Twitter authentication.

Can somebody figure out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

You have to change the superset_config.py. Look at this example config, it works for me.

```
import os
from flask_appbuilder.security.manager import AUTH_OID, 
AUTH_REMOTE_USER, 
AUTH_DB, AUTH_LDAP, AUTH_OAUTH
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
ROW_LIMIT = 5000
SUPERSET_WORKERS = 4
SECRET_KEY = 'a long and random secret key'
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = ‘postgresql://username:pass@host:port/dbname’
CSRF_ENABLED = True
AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_OAUTH
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION = True
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION_ROLE = "Public"
OAUTH_PROVIDERS = [
    {
       'name': 'google',
       'whitelist': ['@company.com'],
   'icon': 'fa-google',
   'token_key': 'access_token', 
   'remote_app': {
        'base_url': 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/',
        'request_token_params': {
              'scope': 'email profile'
            },
        'request_token_url': None,
        'access_token_url':         
        'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
        'authorize_url': 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
        'consumer_key': 'GOOGLE_AUTH_KEY',
        'consumer_secret': 'GOOGLE_AUTH_SECRET'
          }
       }
]
```

Comment: how `SECRET_KEY`, `CSRF_ENABLED` and `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI` related to the Google OAuth configuration?

Comment: this is not related to google auth, it's just the general config file I used everytime required.

Comment: Is this superset config.py file? Do we need to add this whole code snippet?

Answer (score 2):

2021 update: The FAB OAuth provider schema seems like it changed a bit since this answer. If you're trying to do this with Superset >= 1.1.0, try this instead:

```py
OAUTH_PROVIDERS = [
    {
        'name': 'google',
        'icon': 'fa-google',
        'token_key': 'access_token',
        'remote_app': {
            'client_id': 'GOOGLE_KEY',
            'client_secret': 'GOOGLE_SECRET',
            'api_base_url': 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/',
            'client_kwargs':{
              'scope': 'email profile'
            },
            'request_token_url': None,
            'access_token_url': 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
            'authorize_url': 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth'
        }
    }
]
```

Of course, sub out GOOGLE_KEY and GOOGLE_SECRET. The rest should be fine. This was cribbed from the [FAB security docs](https://flask-appbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html) for the next time there is drift.

Comment: Doesn't it send redirect_uri as http ?